# Lazy mapping with hibernate tools?

Tags: java, hibernate, reverse-engineering, hibernate-tools

I have two tables `A` and `B` in my database. I the table `B` I have a reference to the table `A` by an Integer `idA`. (idA is a foreign key for B)
When I do reverse engineering using hibernate-tools, I generate two Java objects.

```
public class A{
  int id;
}
```

and

```
public class B{
  int id;
  A a;
}
```

But I want to have

```
public class B{
  int id;
  int idA;
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution: create a custom `ReverseEngineeringStrategy` and change the return of `excludeForeignKeyAsManytoOne` method to `true`.

```
public class MyReverseEngineeringStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy {

    public MyReverseEngineeringStrategy(ReverseEngineeringStrategy delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean excludeForeignKeyAsManytoOne(String keyname, TableIdentifier fromTable, List fromColumns, TableIdentifier referencedTable, List referencedColumns) {
        return true;
                }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for this you have to update your class manually and then remove any `@OneToOne` annotations or similar tags in XML mapping.

By default, Hibernate suggests you to have entity mapped so you can use at once, without having to fetch it explicitly.